# Monotouch: Right manner for using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: xamarin.ios, design-patterns, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

What's the right manner to use NSNotificationCenter?

I would know if there is a sort of guideline to register and remove observers in a specific class.

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("NSString", Action)
```

is used to register an object as an obsever. How can I deregister an observer? Do I have to save all the observer for a specific class in arrays?

Thank you in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The AddObserver method returns an object of type NSObject.

So you call it like this:

```
NSObject myObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("NSString", Action);
```

And when you want to remove it, call the following:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(myObserver);
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitris. Do you know how is possible to send information (object) to observers?

Comment: and where is the right place to register and deregister observers?

Comment: I treat them the same as events. Add in ViewDidLoad, remove in ViewDidUnload most of the times. As far passing information, haven't looked at it, but consider passing anonymous methods as handlers.